# Click no botão executando tantas vezes quantas tabs tiver

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Tenho a seguinte situação:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#segunda_tab" ><?php echo $array_dia_da_semana_s[0] ?></a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#terca_tab"  ><?php echo $array_dia_da_semana_s[1] ?></a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
<div id="segunda_tab" class="tab-pane tab tab-label fade in active">
    <?php
        $id_linha_tabs = 1;
        echo("<font size='5' style='font-weight:bold;'>" . $array_dia[0] . "</font>");                      
        $data_string = $array_dia[0];
        $dia_da_semana = 0;
        $id_da_tabela = 0;                      
        include('consulta_01_dds.php');                                             
    ?>  
</div>

<div id="terca_tab" class="tab-pane fade">
  <?php
        echo("<font size='5' style='font-weight:bold;'>" . $array_dia[1] . "</font>");                      
        $data_string = $array_dia[1];
        $dia_da_semana = 1;
        $id_da_tabela = 1;                      
        include('consulta_01_dds.php');     
  ?>
</div>
</div>
```

No arquivo consulta_01_dds.php tenho o seguinte código:

```
<br>
<table>
    <td>
        <tr>
            <?php echo($dia_da_semana)?>
        <button class="button1" id="<?php echo($dia_da_semana)?>"><?php echo($dia_da_semana)?>
        </tr>
    </td>
</table>    
<br>


<script>    
     $(function()
    {   
        $('.button1').click(function()
        {
            bb = $(this);
            $(".tab-content div").each(function( index ) 
            {
                if($(this).attr('class').indexOf('active') != -1)
                {   
                    alert(" B Indice3: " + index+ ' value..: '+ $(bb).val()+ ' - id '+ $(bb).attr('id'));

                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

A principio tudo funciona como deveria. As abas aparecem, cada conteudo da aba no seu respectivo lugar, contudo quando aperto o botao da classe button1 o click me retorna o alerta com as informações que pedi corretamente, o problema é que ele me retorna tantas vezes quanto as abas que coloco. Neste caso o alerta aparece 2 vezes.  
Exemplo.. Se eu adicionar mais uma LI com `href="#quarta_feira"` e sua respectiva div `id="quarta_feira"` então o click fará o alert aparecer 3 vezes..
A lógica esta errada? Não é assim que se usa a nav-tabs e o tab-pane?
Desde já agradeço a atenção de todos.

Comment: Qual é a seguinte situação?

Comment: Boa tarde Lucas Costa.. O problema é que o click esta sendo executado tantas vezes quantas abas tive.. e teoricamente :) teria que ser um click uma ação..Abraços :)

Comment: O loop vai ser executado o número de vezes que houver elementos `.tab-content div`.

Comment: @DvD...Que loop?????

Comment: @DvD AGORA entendi o que você disse :)  Então para resolver o problema eu simplismente TIREI o <script> </script> de dentro da pagina consulta_01_dds.php e coloquei ele na pagina que chama o include.. Ai o click do botão passou a responder corretamente :) .. Cara OBRIGADO pela luz. Sou inexperiente nesse negocio de php. Mais uma vez.. Obrigado.

Comment: @DvD Cara...a solução que falei acima só funcionou para a primeira aba (index 0). todas os outros botoes das outras ABAS não ACIONÃO o script..

Comment: Peraí que vou dar uma analisada.

Comment: Esse `$(bb).val()` é o que?

Comment: @DvD é o que esta escrito no botao

Comment: Tá errado isso. Primeira coisa é fechar a tag `<button></button>`... depois pra pegar o q está escrito no button vc deve usar `$(bb).text()`.

Comment: Fiz um teste aqui e funcionam os botões normalmente. O ideal é vc editar sua pergunta e colocar parte do HTML já o que foi retornado pelo PHP, ou seja, o HTML puro com os valores do PHP já retornados.

Comment: Veja o teste a grosso modo que fiz: https://jsfiddle.net/ykr4m01c/

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67258/discussion-between-ricardo-m-souza-and-dvd).